# Build an FA that accepts only the words baa, ab, and abb and no other strings longer or shorter

Tags: computer-science, finite-automata, dfa, nfa, automata-theory

I have been trying solve this problem for a while now for a university assignment. I'm required to build a DFA and an NFA for the above question. So far I have been able to solve the DFA, but can not find a solution for a proper NFA after multiple tries.

#### The solution of my DFA for the language provided above:

[image: The solution of my DFA for the language provided above:]

My attempts for the NFA are down below. I apologize for my messy handwriting but these were just rough works that I was drawing out on the go.

#### My first attempt:

[image: My first attempt at solving the NFA]

#### My second attempt:

[image: My second attempt at solving the NFA]

#### My third attempt:

[image: My third attempt at solving the NFA]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only three words, so just make three parallel paths for your NFA, using a transition function like the following:

| Input State | Input Symbol | Output States |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [start] | a | [a.b], [a.bb] |
| [start] | b | [b.aa] |
| [a.b] | b | [ab#] |
| [a.bb] | b | [ab.b] |
| [ab.b] | b | [abb#] |
| [b.aa] | a | [ba.a] |
| [ba.a] | a | [baa#] |

Here, state names are in brackets ([..]) and state names that end with "#" are terminal.

Generally it's considered easier to make an NFA than a DFA, so the usual method is to first make an NFA and then make the DFA by modifying the NFA by changing multiple output states to a single intermediate state.

If you followed this method for the above NFA, then the resulting DFA would look something like this (I have appended an "*" to the intermediate state names):

| Input State | Input Symbol | Output State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [start] | a | [a.b*] |
| [start] | b | [b.aa] |
| [a.b*] | b | [ab.*] |
| [ab.*] | (e) | [ab#] |
| [ab.*] | b | [abb.*] |
| [abb.*] | (e) | [abb#] |
| [b.aa] | a | [ba.a] |
| [ba.a] | a | [baa#] |

I've been a bit loose about all of the empty symbol/end-of-input transitons to terminal states.  If you need me to fill al of them in, them I can do that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This was really helpful.

Comment: Remember to upvote answers that are helpful, and if this answered your question, to then mark as the answer.